Trying to remove non relevant plot points from a ui.chart.image.series in Google Earth Engine script
I am writing a pretty basic script to calculate the median NDVI in an ROI (in this case titled Naussac) in and then put it in a chart using the ui.chart.image.series function. The chart works, but there are a few points that skew the graph that I would like to remove.
Here is my code:
    /*
Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}


var addIndices = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['ndvi']);

  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};


var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterBounds(Naussac)
                  .filterDate('2022-05-01', '2023-06-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',30))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .map(addIndices);

print(dataset);


Map.centerObject(Naussac,12);

// selects the last image of the dataset and adds it to the map.
var lastimg = dataset.select("ndvi").limit(1, 'system:time_start', false).first();
Map.addLayer(lastimg.clip(Naussac), {}, "ndvi last image")

Map.addLayer(dataset.select("ndvi").first().clip(Naussac), {}, "ndvi fist image");


//TEST GETTING IMAGES OTHER THAN 1st
var dataList = ee.ImageCollection(dataset).toList(25);
var d2Image = ee.Image(ee.List(dataList).get(1)); 
var d3Image = ee.Image(ee.List(dataList).get(2)); 
var d4Image = ee.Image(ee.List(dataList).get(3));

var deletion = 12;
var update = dataList.filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', deletion));
print('original list', dataList);
print('updated', update);

//Second element added to map
Map.addLayer(d2Image.clip(ROI), {max: 0.5, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, "1 Image");
Map.addLayer(d3Image.clip(ROI), {max: 0.5, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, "2 Image");
Map.addLayer(d4Image.clip(ROI), {max: 0.5, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, "3 Image");

Map.addLayer(Naussac);



// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .series({
          imageCollection: dataset.select("ndvi"),
          region: Naussac,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
          scale: 10,
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setSeriesNames([ 'NDVI'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Median Vegetation Index of the Naussac Reservoir in 2022',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date',format: 'MMM-DD', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Vegetation index',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          interpolateNulls: true,
          lineWidth: 5,
          pointSize:7,
          colors: [ 'Green'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
        
print(chart);

I have tried multiple functions such as list.remove, certain null functions and filters, but I cannot get annything to work.
